# SixLabors ImageSharp crop-resizes wrong width and height

Tags: c#, imagesharp

I use SixLabors.ImageSharp to resize photo using below code:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/SixLabors.ImageSharp/
ASP .NET Core 5.0

Input photo: 720x960px
Expect output: 248x186px
Actual result: 186x248px

Why width becomes height and vice versa?

```
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    using var image = Image.Load(bytes);
    image.Mutate(x => x
        .Resize(new ResizeOptions
            {
                Mode = ResizeMode.Crop,
                Position = AnchorPositionMode.Center,
                Size = new Size(248, 186)
            })
        .BackgroundColor(Color.White));

    await image.SaveAsync(stream, new JpegEncoder() { Quality = 85 });
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This will be because your source photo has a metadata flag that has a custom orientation set which causes clients to rotate the image when rendering it/interpreting but in fact the pixel data is really rotated 90 degrees than it appears.

You will want to use the `.AutoOrient()` api to fix that for you, that forces the pixels data to be oriented correctly to the desired orientation.

```cs
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    using var image = Image.Load(bytes);
    image.Mutate(x => x
        .AutoOrient() // this is the important thing that needed adding
        .Resize(new ResizeOptions
            {
                Mode = ResizeMode.Crop,
                Position = AnchorPositionMode.Center,
                Size = new Size(248, 186)
            })
        .BackgroundColor(Color.White));

    await image.SaveAsync(stream, new JpegEncoder() { Quality = 85 });
}
```

Comment: Thanks you so much for saving my day! AutoOrient() fixes this problem.

Comment: you should add `using SixLabors.ImageSharp.Processing;`